# How to translate the output from an lm() fit with a cubic spline into a regression equation

Tags: r, splines

I have some code and output, and I would like to construct a model.  I don't know how to construct a model using this output:

```
 require("splines")
 x   <- c(0.2,   0.23,   0.26,   0.29,   0.33,   0.46,    0.53 )
 y   <- c(0.211, 0.2026, 0.2034, 0.2167, 0.2177, 0.19225, 0.182)
 fit <- lm(y ~ ns(x,3))
 summary(fit)
```

Note that `ns()` generates the B-spline basis matrix for a natural cubic spline.  Thus this model regresses `y` against a B-spline for `x` using three degrees of freedom.  What would the equation for such a model look like?

Comment: Although this concern is of interest here, this question is stated too much in an `R`-centric way--and therefore belongs on SO--unless you explain what `ns` does.  (It's not even part of `R`: what package does it come from?)

Comment: @whuber, see here: [?ns](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/splines/html/ns.html); `ns()` is part of the splines package. I recognize that this question is couched in R terms, but my opinion is that it's on-topic here.

Comment: @gung Yes, I was able to find the package too, but that's not the point: for this question to stay here it needs to be made intelligible even to non-R users.

Comment: @whuber I've added a minor bit of explanation. Are you looking for more that this?

Comment: @Gavin Thank you.  I have taken the liberty of adding one more line so that non-R users can understand what is being asked (and perhaps, therefore, offer meaningful answers).

Comment: @whuber On the belonging on [so], this would get short shrift there. There is nothing about programming here. You'd just be as likely to see it migrated here *from* [so] if it had been posted there first :-)

Comment: @Gavin I don't think that's our problem :-). By offering a programming solution (with no statistical explanation at all!), Frank Harrell has beautifully demonstrated the sense in which this *can* be construed as a pure programming problem.

Comment: @whuber touché!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
require(rms)
f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x, 3))  # 2 d.f. for x
Function(f)  # represent fitted function in simplest R form
latex(f)     # typeset algebraic representation of fit
```

rcs "restricted cublic spline" is another representation of a natural spline.

Comment: That is impressive.  But I think the answer one would look for on this site (as opposed to SO) would explain how, in general, one determines the equation of a spline.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why the coefficients produced by f are different than the coefficients produced by fit?

Comment: There are different basis function representations for splines.  `ns` generates orthogonal (uncorrelated) terms that are harder to interpret whereas `rcs` uses the truncated power basis which is easy to represent in an equation.  Think about this example: you could have a model with $X$ and $X^{2}$ or you could fit $X-\bar{X}$ and $(X-\bar{X})^{2}$.  The latter's terms would be orthogonal but harder to interpret in terms of raw variables.