# Fitted model of linear spline regression in R

Tags: r, regression

If the linear model is fitted as follows, what is the formula of the fitted model?  I need to use the coefficients outside R.

```
fit <- lm( y ~ bs( x, degree=1, knots=c(6,12,18) ) );

Coefficients:
(Intercept)                    9.2679
ns(x, knots = c(6, 12, 18))1   5.3064
ns(x, knots = c(6, 12, 18))2   5.1313
ns(x, knots = c(6, 12, 18))3   6.1153
ns(x, knots = c(6, 12, 18))4   1.3724
```

Comment: see `Function` and `latex.rms` in package `rms` -- they may be of some help

Comment: @Glen_b: They only convert natural splines generated with `rcs` to the truncated power basis, unfortunately.

Comment: @Scortchi Hmm. Okay, thanks. I must have been thinking of something else - I'm sure Frank had something in there to help with this.

Comment: Try pmin(x - yourknot, 0)... The first knot will be 0, I suspect...

Answer (score 5):

The coefficients have the usual interpretation, but for the B-spline basis functions; which you can generate for new data easily enough in R :

```
bs(x, degree=1, knots=c(6,12,18)) -> x.bspline.bff
new.x <- c(10.2, 11.8, 13, 30)
predict(x.bspline.bff, new.x)
```

Most software will have functions to generate these (e.g. [SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm), [Stata](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/4794073_BSPLINE_Stata_modules_to_compute_B-splines_parameterized_by_their_values_at_reference_points)); should you need to do it yourself, a recursive procedure is given in [Hastie et.al (2009), *The Elements of Statistical Learning*](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), Ch.5, "Appendix: Computational considerations for splines".

You could also use an equivalent reëxpression with truncated power functions, but in general that's not a good idea—there's a danger of numerical instability with higher order splines & interactions. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97845/interpreting-spline-results/97876#97876) for an example of exporting a spline function to Excel.