Why are GAM regressions useful if we can't recover their full equation?
I have seen multiple questions on this topic (GAM Regression), but have never seen a full answer on this:

I have fitted an equation using GAMs (generalized additive models) in R using model1 <- mgcv::gam( x1..xn). How do i get the equation format?
How to obtain the model coefficients of GAM in R?
What is the mathematical model formula corresponding to this gam model fit in R?
How to obtain the model coefficients of GAM in R?
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_write_out_a_complete_GAM_model_as_an_equation

Suppose I have some data and fit a GAM model using R:
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(splines)

set.seed(123)
slope <- 0.05 

data <- rbind(
    data.frame(
        x = 1:100,
        y = rnorm(100, mean = 2.5, sd = 1.2) + (1:100) * slope
    ),
    data.frame(
        x = 101:160,
        y = rnorm(60, mean = -1.8, sd = 1.5) + (101:160) * slope
    ),
    data.frame(
        x = 161:200,
        y = rnorm(40, mean = 4.2, sd = 1.8) + (161:200) * slope
    ),
    data.frame(
        x = 201:225,
        y = rnorm(25, mean = 0.3, sd = 1.4) + (201:225) * slope
    ),
    data.frame(
        x = 226:240,
        y = rnorm(15, mean = 3.7, sd = 1.6) + (226:240) * slope
    )
)

pred_data <- data.frame(x = seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = 200))

# GAM
gam_model <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = data)
pred_data$gam <- predict(gam_model, newdata = pred_data)

# Natural Splines
ns_model <- lm(y ~ ns(x, df = 10), data = data)
pred_data$ns <- predict(ns_model, newdata = pred_data)

#LOESS
loess_model <- loess(y ~ x, data = data, span = 0.25)
pred_data$loess <- predict(loess_model, newdata = pred_data)

# Polynomial Regression
poly_model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = 5), data = data)
pred_data$poly <- predict(poly_model, newdata = pred_data)

# GAM with different basis
gam_model2 <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", k = 20), data = data)
pred_data$gam2 <- predict(gam_model2, newdata = pred_data)

pred_long <- pred_data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(gam, ns, loess, poly, gam2),
                 names_to = "model",
                 values_to = "predicted")

p1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.5, size = 0.8) +
    geom_line(data = pred_long, aes(x = x, y = predicted, color = model), linewidth = 1) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Comparison of Different Regression Models",
         x = "X", y = "Y") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("gam" = "blue", 
                                  "ns" = "red", 
                                  "loess" = "green", 
                                  "poly" = "purple",
                                  "gam2" = "orange"),
                       labels = c("GAM (default)", 
                                  "Natural Splines", 
                                  "LOESS", 
                                  "Polynomial (degree 5)",
                                  "GAM (cubic regression)")) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p2 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.5, size = 0.8) +
    geom_line(data = pred_long, aes(x = x, y = predicted)) +
    facet_wrap(~model, ncol = 2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Individual Model Fits",
         x = "X", y = "Y")

print(p1)
print(p2)


For GAM models, it seems that it is fundamentally impossible to obtain an equation for the fitted model.
I have looked and looked on how this might be possible, and the only thing which makes sense to me is the following: After fitting the GAM model, predict multiple values of $y$ over a range of $x$ values , then fit a simpler model to these predicted values to approximate the GAM model (in a situation with multiple variables, you would hold all other variables at their mean value and just do this for one predictor and the response). This is my interpretation on how to do this in R:
# create grid for predictions
x_grid <- seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = 500)
gam_preds <- predict(gam_model, newdata = data.frame(x = x_grid))

# fit different models to GAM predictions

poly_model <- lm(gam_preds ~ poly(x_grid, degree = 5, raw = TRUE))
poly_preds <- predict(poly_model)

ns_model <- lm(gam_preds ~ ns(x_grid, df = 8))
ns_preds <- predict(ns_model)

loess_model <- loess(gam_preds ~ x_grid, span = 0.2)
loess_preds <- predict(loess_model)

calc_stats <- function(actual, predicted) {
    r2 <- round(cor(actual, predicted)^2, 4)
    rmse <- round(sqrt(mean((actual - predicted)^2)), 4)
    return(c(r2 = r2, rmse = rmse))
}

stats_poly <- calc_stats(gam_preds, poly_preds)
stats_ns <- calc_stats(gam_preds, ns_preds)
stats_loess <- calc_stats(gam_preds, loess_preds)

# Create equation for polynomial
coefs <- round(coef(poly_model), 4)
eq_terms <- character(length(coefs))
eq_terms[1] <- sprintf("%.4f", coefs[1])
for(i in 1:(length(coefs)-1)) {
    term <- sprintf("%.4fx%s", coefs[i+1], 
                    if(i == 1) "" else if(i == 2) "²" else if(i == 3) "³" else paste0("^", i))
    eq_terms[i+1] <- if(coefs[i+1] >= 0) paste0(" + ", term) else paste0(" - ", abs(coefs[i+1]))
}
poly_eq <- paste0("y = ", paste(eq_terms, collapse = ""))

plot_data <- data.frame(
    x = x_grid,
    GAM = gam_preds,
    Polynomial = poly_preds,
    Natural_Splines = ns_preds,
    LOESS = loess_preds
)

plot_data_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(plot_data, 
                                      cols = -x, 
                                      names_to = "Model", 
                                      values_to = "y")

p1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(data = plot_data_long, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Model, linetype = Model), 
              linewidth = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("GAM" = "black", 
                                  "Polynomial" = "red", 
                                  "Natural_Splines" = "blue",
                                  "LOESS" = "purple")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "All Models Comparison",
         subtitle = paste0("R² values:\n",
                           "Polynomial: ", stats_poly["r2"], "\n",
                           "Natural Splines: ", stats_ns["r2"], "\n",
                           "LOESS: ", stats_loess["r2"]),
         x = "x", y = "y") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")


labels <- list(
    GAM = paste0("Original GAM\n",
                 "Smoothing spline with default parameters"),
    Polynomial = paste0("Polynomial (degree 5)\n",
                        str_wrap(poly_eq, width = 30), "\n",
                        "R² = ", stats_poly["r2"], "\n",
                        "RMSE = ", stats_poly["rmse"]),
    Natural_Splines = paste0("Natural Splines\n",
                             "Degrees of freedom = 8\n",
                             "R² = ", stats_ns["r2"], "\n",
                             "RMSE = ", stats_ns["rmse"]),
    LOESS = paste0("LOESS\n",
                   "span = 0.2\n",
                   "R² = ", stats_loess["r2"], "\n",
                   "RMSE = ", stats_loess["rmse"])
)

p2 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(data = plot_data_long, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Model), 
              linewidth = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~Model, ncol = 2) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("GAM" = "black", 
                                  "Polynomial" = "red", 
                                  "Natural_Splines" = "blue",
                                  "LOESS" = "purple")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Individual Model Fits",
         x = "x", y = "y") +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(
        Model = names(labels),
        x = rep(min(data$x), length(labels)),
        y = rep(max(data$y) + 1, length(labels)),
        label = unlist(labels)
    ),
    aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
    hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 2.5)

combined_plot <- p1 | p2


Thus, the natural question arises:

Is this the correct methodology to obtain the model equation of the fitted GAM regression? (seems like we are introducing a new source of uncertainty/error proprogation)
If we can't get the final equation for the fitted GAM regression model, why not just fit a simpler regression model (e.g. cubic spline) on the original data that is able to directly provide the final fitted model equation?



x_grid <- seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = 500)
gam_preds <- predict(gam_model, newdata = data.frame(x = x_grid))

cubic_model <- lm(gam_preds ~ ns(x_grid, df = 4))  # using 4 degrees of freedom for simplicity
cubic_preds <- predict(cubic_model)

calc_stats <- function(actual, predicted) {
    r2 <- round(cor(actual, predicted)^2, 4)
    rmse <- round(sqrt(mean((actual - predicted)^2)), 4)
    return(c(r2 = r2, rmse = rmse))
}

stats_cubic <- calc_stats(gam_preds, cubic_preds)

basis_matrix <- ns(x_grid, df = 4)
coef_cubic <- coef(cubic_model)

eq_terms <- sprintf("%.4f", coef_cubic[1])  # intercept
for(i in 1:length(coef_cubic[-1])) {
    term <- sprintf("%.4f × NS%d(x)", coef_cubic[i+1], i)
    eq_terms <- paste(eq_terms, ifelse(coef_cubic[i+1] >= 0, "+", ""), term)
}
cubic_eq <- paste("y =", eq_terms)

plot_data <- data.frame(
    x = x_grid,
    GAM = gam_preds,
    `Cubic Spline` = cubic_preds
)

plot_data_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(plot_data, 
                                      cols = -x, 
                                      names_to = "Model", 
                                      values_to = "y")

p1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(data = plot_data_long, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Model, linetype = Model), 
              linewidth = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("GAM" = "black", "Cubic Spline" = "red")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Cubic Spline Approximation of GAM Model",
         subtitle = paste0("Natural Cubic Spline with 4 df\n",
                           "R² to GAM predictions = ", stats_cubic["r2"], "\n",
                           "RMSE to GAM predictions = ", stats_cubic["rmse"]),
         x = "x", 
         y = "GAM Predictions (and Cubic Spline Approximation)",
         color = "Model",
         linetype = "Model") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

labels <- list(
    GAM = "Original GAM Model\n(Reference model being approximated)",
    `Cubic Spline` = paste0("Natural Cubic Spline Approximation\n",
                            "Degrees of freedom = 4\n",
                            str_wrap(cubic_eq, width = 40), "\n",
                            "R² to GAM predictions = ", stats_cubic["r2"], "\n",
                            "RMSE to GAM predictions = ", stats_cubic["rmse"])
)

p2 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(data = plot_data_long, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Model), 
              linewidth = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~Model, ncol = 2) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("GAM" = "black", "Cubic Spline" = "red")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Cubic Spline Approximation of GAM Predictions",
         x = "x", 
         y = "GAM Predictions (and Cubic Spline Approximation)") +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(
        Model = names(labels),
        x = rep(min(data$x), length(labels)),
        y = rep(max(data$y) + 1, length(labels)),
        label = unlist(labels)
    ),
    aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
    hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 2.5)

combined_plot <- p1 | p2

print(combined_plot)
cat("\nCubic Spline Equation:\n", cubic_eq)


The equation for your GAM is $\hat{y}i = \gamma + \sum{k=1}^{K} \beta_k b_k(x_{i})$.

Hi Gavin Simpson, thank your for writing. I am just wondering, how do we get the equation of the fitted GAM? I need the full and exact equation of the fitted GAM ... is it possible to obtain this? (e.g. i want to take derivatives and integrals of the fitted GAM model equation in a future application ... how can I do this)?

Where $b_k(x_i)$ is the value of the $k$th basis function evaluated at the covariate value $x_i$. Hence $b()$ is some function, which is typically more complex than for a polynomial but if we define $b_k$ to be the function $x_i^{k}$ we have exactly your polynomial model for polynomials of order $K$.

Derivatives are pretty easy with finite differences (see gratia::derivatives() for one implementation of this) and integration could be done similarly via the trapezoid method (or perhaps other ways - I've not thought much about that problem) - often enough, simply summing over the fitted response has been sufficient for my needs for example.

The problem with what you ask is that $b()$ is typically complicated, even for simple things like cubic splines; for the default spline in mgcv, the $b_k$ are radial basis functions the set of which have been subjected to an eigen decomposition, so even if it is possible to derive the thing you want it may well require some heavy (i.e. beyond one's capabilities) math (my own are limited enough that I just use brute force, hence the finite differences).

I think the crux of your question or confusion is implicit. Why exactly do you think we need the explicit model equation? For what purpose?

You can cut through all that by using regression splines, which give you equations and will fit very similar to GAMs. See for example this.

Asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97845.

@FrankHarrell What makes you think these aren't regression splines? At least the ones fitted in gam() are.

@GavinSimpson :Thank you for all this information . In your opinion, is this approach that I am using (fitting a simpler model to the GAM predictions) acceptable?

Sorry I missed the use of ns and poly which uses very parametric fits.  If you think those are messy to deal with (I usually agree) then I would recommend using what I almost always use: restricted cubic splines (natural splines with truncated power basis).  The R rms package has a latex method that renders fitted equations in simplest form when using restricted cubic splines.

@FrankHarrell : Great discussion... do you know if what I am doing is correct? is (fitting a simpler model to the GAM predictions) acceptable?

Probably so though SEs will be tough to get.  I'd use the other approach though.

Why would you need an equation at all? You have a model, and you can probe it in any way you like.

Regardless of whether you can get the equation (see the comments), the sort of curves that you show in your question are inherently useful. They show the relationship in all its curvy messiness. This is sometimes more useful than an equation.
True, the complexity of any equation (if you can derive one) makes interpretation of the parameters tricky, but sometimes you don't need that. As Yogi Berra may have said "You can see a lot by looking."

Peter:  do you think what I have done is correct? fitting a simpler model to the GAM predictions is acceptable?

I think you'd want to do it on different data. Train and test.  But others here are more expert on that question

Another reason, perhaps not explicitly mentioned so far, is that sometimes you have an irregular trend in the data that you want to remove because is of technical, uninteresting nature. So you fit a flexible model like gam and work with the residuals from then on. A separate question at this point would be why you would choose gam over loess or spline.

Sometimes, all you need is a shape.
You can use the fitted GAM to predict what the value should be across the full range of data - isn't that line/curve often what we want from a fit anyway? It's less convenient to use that as input into some more complex operation (say a dynamic model) than a simple equation & parameter values. But even that can be done with some effort - I've used fitted GAMs inside ODE models.

mkt: do you think what I have done is correct? fitting a simpler model to the GAM predictions is acceptable?

@user_436830 No, I don't really see the point of it, honestly. If you really want a  polynomial, you can just fit a polynomial to start with and skip the GAM. Fitting one model and then approximating it with another could add noise and doesn't help in an obvious way.

mkt: thanks for the clarification. here is my intention:

I observed some data on the number of arrivals that happen at each time unit. I want to model the arrivals vs time as a GAM regression model ... and then simulate a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process with a Rate/Intensity function based on the fitted GAM model on the arrival data.  This is why I wanted the equation of the GAM...

@user_436830 I really don't see why you don't just predict from your fitted model for the x.grid values (times?) you want to include in the simulation? Perhaps start a new question and explain what you want to actually do, not some bit 10 steps down a rabbit hole that you happen to wandered. For the record, no I think what you are doing to approximate the GAM fit with another model doesn't make sense, at least given what you have told us.

@user_436830 That is context that really ought to be in your question. I agree with Gavin that you ought to open a new one and state your real question.

@GavinSimpson : here is my question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657336/creating-a-non-homogenous-queue
