Creating a non-homogenous queue based on another statistical model?
I have a question on how construct/approximate a statistical queue based on changing parameters.
I created/simulated this approximate version of a MMK queue in R:
library(tidyverse)

k <- 3       # number of servers
lambda <- 2  # arrival rate
mu <- 1      # service rate per server
T <- 100     # simulation time
n_sims <- 20 # number of simulations
dt <- 0.05   # time step
initial_n <- 100  # initial queue length

simulate_mmk <- function(sim_number) {
    n_steps <- ceiling(T/dt)
    queue_length <- numeric(n_steps)
    queue_length[1] <- initial_n
    
    arrivals <- rpois(n_steps, lambda * dt)
    departures <- rpois(n_steps, k * mu * dt)
    
    for(i in 2:n_steps) {
        current_n <- queue_length[i-1]
        arrival <- arrivals[i]
        departure <- min(departures[i], current_n)
        queue_length[i] <- current_n + arrival - departure
    }
    
    data.frame(
        time = seq(0, T-dt, length.out=n_steps),
        queue_length = queue_length,
        simulation = factor(sim_number)
    )
}

set.seed(123)
sim_data <- bind_rows(
    lapply(1:n_sims, function(i) {
        set.seed(123 + i)
        simulate_mmk(i)
    })
)


I am interested in adapting this queue that allows for a changing number of arrivals, departures and servers.
For example, in the above simulation, the number of servers is held constant and arrivals and departures are randomly chosen from probability distributions with fixed parameters. I want to make something in which these distributions can vary as time goes on.
For example, suppose the arrivals, departures and servers vary with time (e.g. piecewise, probability distribution with changing values of time).
Could I just generate vectors of arrivals, departures and servers based on these changing distributions beforehand (e.g. fit regression models to historical arrival, departure and server data) and then simulate random data from these models to create a non-homogenous queue?
run_sims <- function(n_sims = 20, T = 100, dt = 0.05, initial_n = 100) {

    n_steps <- ceiling(T/dt)
    
    set.seed(123)
    arrivals <- abs(rnorm(n_steps, mean = 25, sd = 2))
    service_rates <- abs(rnorm(n_steps, mean = 15, sd = 1))
    servers <- abs(rnorm(n_steps, mean = 5, sd = 0.5))
    
    sim_data <- map_dfr(1:n_sims, function(i) {
        set.seed(123 + i)
        
        queue_length <- numeric(n_steps)
        queue_length[1] <- initial_n
        
        for(i in 2:n_steps) {
            current_n <- queue_length[i-1]
            arrival <- rpois(1, arrivals[i] * dt)
            departure <- min(rpois(1, servers[i] * service_rates[i] * dt), current_n)
            queue_length[i] <- current_n + arrival - departure
        }
        
        data.frame(
            time = seq(0, T-dt, length.out=n_steps),
            queue_length = queue_length,
            simulation = factor(i)
        )
    })
    return(sim_data)
}

sim_data <- run_sims(
    n_sims = 20,
    T = 100,
    dt = 0.05,
    initial_n = 100
)



Clarifications:

First, I would fit 3 different models (e.g.  GAM/time series) to historical arrival, departure and server data
Then, I would forecast future values from these 3 models over some range of time
Then, at each time point in this range - I would simulate an arrival, departure and server number from a probability distribution (e.g. exponential, poisson) centered around each forecasted value produced by the 3 models
Repeat


In a post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129322 I explained how to engineer this kind of simulation and provided a working example to emulate.

thank you ... this was the motivation to my question on GAM models I had posted earlier. I wanted to fit GAM regressions to historical arrivals and departure data ... and then simulate from poisson/exponential distributions centered around forecasts from the fitted GAMs

any other comments? does my approach look correct to you?

It sounds reasonable. Do you have real data to compare to? The best way to answer the question "is my approach correct" is to generate data using your approach and then see how well it matches real life data

Andrew Gelman talks about this a lot (in a Bayesian context, but the general ideas still fit here). See a bunch of recommendations in this blog post
