# Interpretion natural spline function ov IV in ordinal regression

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, splines, ordered-logit, effects

I know that this question was already posed several times but I am not sure If I really got the interpretation for spline functions right.

I have an ordered model that is regressed on an index ranging from ca. 0.028 to 0.42 for which I created a natural spline with `splines::ns(X, 3)`.

Below you can see an example from the "housing" dataset with the variable Freq. If I look at the modelsummary I get three coefficients for `ns(Freq, 3)`. When looking at the information from `ns(Freq, 3)` I get two boundary knots and two inner knots. Thus I'd interpret the coefficients as: When Freq<Knot_1 an 1 unit increase in Freq increases the probability for satisfation == High c.p. on average by 0.75... But if I use `ggpredict` and calculate slopes between the boundaries (dashed lines) I don't come to the same numbers.

So question:

Is it right to interpret the coefficients like I did, and: are the higher coefficients `(ns(X,3)2` and `ns(X,3)3)` all relative to the baseline (outer knot_low) or relative to the last knot?

EXAMPLE:

```r
> housing %>% glimpse
Rows: 72
Columns: 5
$ Sat  <ord> Low, Medium, High, Low, Medium, High, Low, Medium, High, Low, Medium, High, Low, Medium, High, Low, Medium, High, Low…
$ Infl <fct> Low, Low, Low, Medium, Medium, Medium, High, High, High, Low, Low, Low, Medium, Medium, Medium, High, High, High, Low…
$ Type <fct> Tower, Tower, Tower, Tower, Tower, Tower, Tower, Tower, Tower, Apartment, Apartment, Apartment, Apartment, Apartment,…
$ Cont <fct> Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Low, Lo…
$ Freq <int> 21, 21, 28, 34, 22, 36, 10, 11, 36, 61, 23, 17, 43, 35, 40, 26, 18, 54, 13, 9, 10, 8, 8, 12, 6, 7, 9, 18, 6, 7, 15, 1…
> 
> # ##get knots information
> # ns(housing$Freq,3)
> # attr(,"degree")
> # [1] 3
> # attr(,"knots")
> # 33.33333% 66.66667% 
> #        13        23 
> # attr(,"Boundary.knots")
> # [1]  3 86
> # attr(,"intercept")
> # [1] FALSE
> # attr(,"class")
> # [1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"
> 
> tibble( Knots = c("out_low", "inner_1", "inner_2", "out_high"), 
+         Val = c(3,13,23,86 ))-> splinetab
> splinetab
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Knots      Val
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 out_low      3
2 inner_1     13
3 inner_2     23
4 out_high    86
> #
> clm(Sat ~ ns(Freq, 3), data = housing) %>% S
formula: Sat ~ ns(Freq, 3)
data:    housing

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  72   -77.98 165.96 3(0)  4.96e-08 1.6e+02

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
ns(Freq, 3)1   0.7342     1.1112   0.661    0.509
ns(Freq, 3)2   2.1358     1.7693   1.207    0.227
ns(Freq, 3)3   0.5048     1.5248   0.331    0.741

Threshold coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value
Low|Medium    0.2328     0.7435   0.313
Medium|High   1.6539     0.7687   2.152
> 
> #
> ggeffect(clm(Sat ~ ns(Freq, 3), data = housing), terms = "Freq [3,13,23,86]") %>% filter(response.level == "High")-> ge
> ge
# Predicted probabilities of Sat

Freq | Predicted |       95% CI
-------------------------------
   3 |      0.16 | [0.04, 0.46]
  13 |      0.34 | [0.20, 0.52]
  23 |      0.39 | [0.25, 0.54]
  86 |      0.35 | [0.03, 0.91]
> #
> ggplot(ge, aes(x= x, y = predicted))+geom_smooth()+geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3), lty = 3)+geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 13), lty = 3)+geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 23), lty = 3)+geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 86), lty = 3)
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it right to interpret the coefficients like I did, and: are the higher coefficients (`ns(X,3)2` and `ns(X,3)3`) all relative to the baseline (outer knot_low) or relative to the last knot?

There is no simple heuristic interpretation of spline-term coefficients, particularly when `ns()` is used. The coefficients have to be interpreted in terms of how the spline is expressed in the model matrix for the regression. The `ns()` function uses a B-spline basis of orthogonal polynomials, leading to the following with the example data.

```
library(splines)
library(MASS) ## for housing data
## put the "Freq" values into ascending order 
orderedFreq <- housing$Freq[order(housing$Freq)]
mmNS <- model.matrix(~ ns(orderedFreq, 3))
plot(mmNS[,2]~orderedFreq,type="l",bty="n",ylab="Spline components",ylim=c(-0.5,1))
lines(mmNS[,3]~orderedFreq,type="l",col="red")
lines(mmNS[,4]~orderedFreq,type="l",col="blue")
title(main="ns(orderedFreq,3)")
```

[image: ns() spline]

I think that illustrates the futility of trying for a simple interpretation of the corresponding regression coefficients.

The `rcs()` function in the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) comes closer to what you want. It uses a different spline basis, resulting in the following for these data:

```
library(rms)
mmRCS <- model.matrix(~ rcs(orderedFreq, c(3,13,23,86))) ## to match knots chosen by ns()
plot(mmRCS[,2]~orderedFreq,type="l",bty="n")
lines(mmRCS[,3]~orderedFreq,type="l",col="red")
lines(mmRCS[,4]~orderedFreq,type="l",col="blue")
title(main="rcs(orderedFreq, c(3,13,23,86))")
```

[image: rcs() spline]

This starts with a simple linear term and adds nonlinear terms. Section 2.4 of [Frank Harrell's course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) goes into the details of this spline basis. As he [explains in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/67611/28500), this leads more naturally to expression of the model in terms of an equation, which can be shown via the `Function()` function in the `rms` package. Also, unlike `ns()`, `rcs()` doesn't by default place the outermost knots at the outermost data points.

I think of interpreting individual spline-term coefficients as a "don't try this at home" type of thing, unless you really know what you're doing. Use built-in prediction functions to document the shape and confidence intervals of the associations of the continuous predictor with outcome.

To illustrate, here's a proportional odds model built with `rms` tools. Note that those tools are designed to work with each other, so you can't just apply them to your `clm()` model. This doesn't exactly match your model, as it doesn't put knots at the extremes and it models exceedance probabilities.

```
ddHousing <- datadist(housing) 
options(datadist="ddHousing") ## sets up a datadist to simplify later use of Predict
lrmMod <- lrm(Sat~rcs(Freq,3),data=housing)
ggplot(Predict(lrmMod))
```

[image: predicted log odds]

`Function()` produces an R function for the linear predictor of the model. You'll notice that the `pmax()` terms show the changes of the function at each of the knot locations.

```
lrmFunction <- Function(lrmMod)
lrmFunction
##function(Freq = 19.5) {+0.05079445* Freq-3.1467476e-05*pmax(Freq-6,0)^3+4.2795767e-05*pmax(Freq-19.5,0)^3-1.1328291e-05*pmax(Freq-57,0)^3 }
##<environment: 0x7fa627d9c368>
```

You can get Latex code for the model with `latex(lrmMod)`, which provides the following after a bit of adjustment into MathJax.

$$
{\rm Prob}\{{\rm Sat}\geq j\} = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\alpha_{j}-X\hat\beta)}, {\rm \ \ where} \\ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{\alpha}_{\rm Medium} &=&-0.06570302\\
\hat{\alpha}_{\rm High} &=&-1.48320190\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
$$
{X\hat{\beta}=}\\
  + 0.05079445   {\rm Freq}-3.146748\!\times\!10^{-5}({\rm Freq}-6)_{+}^{3}+4.279577\!\times\!10^{-5 }({\rm Freq}-19.5)_{+}^{3}  \\
-1.132829\!\times\!10^{-5}({\rm Freq}-57)_{+}^{3}  \\
\text{and} \left((x)_{+}=x \text{ if } (x > 0), 0 \text{  otherwise}\right).\\
$$

Comment: FOA thank you. I thought something like this... 
I also went through the course notes and his boot (...not in detail for time reasons...). BTW the book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-19425-7 is really great!  

I tried the orm function but could not enter weights (I have survey data with weights). Do you know about an option for that? 

And also I couldn't find this Function() function...

Comment: I went through the book but I still don't get the "Formula" of my model. What would be the interpretation of the restricted cubic splines?

Comment: @Eco007 I added examples for `Predict()` and `Function()` with the `lrm()` function, which allows for case weights and ordinal regression. The `orm()` function is designed more for modeling continuous outcomes via proportional odds. Both `ns()` and `rcs()` use restricted cubic splines, which are "restricted" in that the functions are linear beyond the outer knots. That's hard to tell with `ns()` as its default outermost knots are at the limits of the values. Those two functions use different spline bases and default knot locations.

Comment: :-) Thanks a lot!! So only few questions: 

the $(x)_+ = x \ \text{for}\  x>0$ stands for the linearity in $x$? 

here I get two coefficients `rcs(x, 3)` and `rcs(x,3)'`. The latter is the first derivative of the spline function?

And would you advise to use the `rcs` function within a `clm` model? When I use interactions terms together with the spline it tells me anyway that the model is unidentifiable because of too large eigenvalues...

Comment: @Eco007 that $(x)_+$ form (or `pmax(x,0)` in the `lrmFunction`) represents a step change in the equation  when the argument $x$ exceeds 0. In the full equation there are several such arguments (like in $(\text{Freq}-6)_+$, where $x=\text{Freq}-6$) representing whether the predictor value has exceeded one or more of the knots. All those terms here, however, are _cubic_ terms. The `rcs(x,3)` coefficient is for the linear component of the spline fit, but the `'`/`''` indicators from `rcs()` don't represent derivatives, just higher-level non-linear terms. Don't try to interpret them individually.

Comment: @Eco007 although you could in principle try to use `rcs()` in the `clm()` function, as it just defines a different model matrix to describe the spline, I can see how that different parameterization versus `ns()` might lead to numeric problems as `clm()` wasn't designed to handle `rcs()` terms.  Note the numerical scale differences in the plots of spline components versus predictor values. If you want to get a formal equation, stick with the `rms` tools and use `lrm()`, with weights as appropriate.

Comment: Doh, ok... why can't relationships pretend to be linear??? :-( I also plotted the predicted probabilties from an `rsc(x,3)` and a `poly(x,2)` which seemed relatively equal but I am still not sure how to present the thing.... 
What would you recommend? It is an index of fractionalization ranging from 0.028 to 0.428. I thought of just using a log/ dichotomizing or using a polynomial. But I also don't get the function behind the command `poly(x,2)`. It is not $ X \beta = X + X^2 $ right? If I simply use `y ~ x + I(x^2) ` it also throws an error that my model has too large eigenvalues.

Comment: @Eco007 a fit with a `poly()` predictor term too often behaves poorly. Dichotomization is [not a good choice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500). Stick with splines. Plots (with confidence limits) of log-odds versus predictor (as I show in the answer) or of probability versus predictor, or examples of particular predictor-variable combinations of interest, are ways to present your results.

Comment: yes I decided to print the model with a natural spline within an effect plot! Because the relationship prints as an inverted U-shape I then picked the peaks and did two regressions. I think this is also a point seeing that a relationship (fractionalization index - tax morale) turns negative after some point :-) I also don't think that interactions with polynomial terms are more easy to interpret than spline functions :-D