# When to square a variable (age) in a poisson regression?

Tags: r, modeling, poisson-regression

I cant seem to find a clear answer to my question.
I have as a dependent variable a count ( number of times certain companies appeared in the news). One of my explanatory variables is age of the company.

would it make sense to square age in such a Poisson regression?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: It depends on your research question. Is it reasonable to expect non-linearity in the age variable? What does the literature say to that?

Answer (score 4):

The answer isn't different for a [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) versus others. You are generally wise to include nonlinear terms in continuous predictors like `age`. You are even wiser if you use a regression spline instead of a fixed polynomial.

There seldom is an exact linear relationship between a continuous predictor like `age` and the outcome that's modeled directly by the [linear predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictor_function), `log(counts)` in a Poisson regression with a log link. Frank Harrell suggests a generally useful strategy: deciding first how much complexity you can devote to fitting each of your predictors, then devoting the corresponding number of degrees of freedom to each of them in a way that avoids overfitting. See Chapter 4 of his [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) or [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/).

A simple quadratic form as you propose is seldom wise, however, as it assumes a strict functional relationship between `age` and `log(counts)`. A regression spline allows the data to help show the form of the relationship. The second chapters of the Harrell references go into more detail. [Generalized additive models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model) are another approach to handle nonlinearities.

Comment: This is a question to EdM, not an answer, I dont have enough points to post this as comment so I apologies in advance. My question is, how does one interpret the coeffects from spline model ?

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai don't try to interpret the individual coefficients from a spline fit unless you really understand spline bases. The coefficients depend on the way the spline is constructed, which differs among implementations. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/569210/28500) for extensive discussion. What's best is to display the overall association over a range of reasonable values.